# Use Meteor JS to write command line tool?

Tags: javascript, configuration, meteor

According to meteor documentation, a fundamental `webapp` package is installed every time you run `meteor create` to provide the "webapp" functionality in your meteor app.  The [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#webapp) says:

> ...You can easily build a Meteor app without it - for example if you wanted to make a command-line tool that still used the Meteor package system and DDP.

I understood this as "you can remove the package", but when I run `meteor remove webapp` it spits this back:

```
webapp is not in this project.
```

1. Why is it telling me this package is not in the project?
2. How do I remove it so I can take advantage of packages and ddp to write command line utilities without having to tie up a port for an unnecessary webserver?

Comment: The package you're looking for is actually named `meteor-platform` https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/meteor-platform/package.js

Comment: There is no github readme, and searching for "Meteor js platform package" and various permutations are yielding no information.  What does this package do?

Comment: From the source code you can tell it's just adding every standard packages to your app, but it does nothing on itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, every meteor app needs a main function and if you use meteor-platform, the webapp package will be automatically added which includes a main. You can remove meteor-platform, which is a wrapper package that does api.imply of all the core meteor packages, and add the packages you need from meteor manually, such as mongo, tracker, etc., and then add a main function.

I have written a blog post about writing command line programs with meteor:

http://practicalmeteor.com/writing-command-line-programs-with-meteor/

In addition, as part of writing many command line programs with meteor, we created the [pracitcalmeteor:mcli](https://atmospherejs.com/practicalmeteor/mcli) package which provides you with some nice extras, including command registration, command line options and argument parsing, and tools to run your commands in development mode, where command line parsing is not possible out of the box. Let me know how it works for you.

Cheers,
Ronen

Comment: This is a very helpful response.  I'll see if this solves my problem soon and get back to mark as accepted.  Thank you, Ronen.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay, did you check it out?

Comment: I did, sorry for the wait.  Excellent blog post, btw!