# Is there a Meteor Task Runner?

Tags: meteor

Is there a task runner for meteor ? I mean something like rake for Rails. I need to run a script with access to the meteor server environment (ie like running a script inside a meteor shell)

Comment: Have you tried to post here https://forums.meteor.com/ ?
I'm also interested in this question.

Comment: No I haven't posted to the meteor forums in fact

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this post : [Use Meteor JS to write command line tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247875/use-meteor-js-to-write-command-line-tool)

And it refers to this page : http://practicalmeteor.com/writing-command-line-programs-with-meteor/

Comment: thanks but that's not exactly what I'm looking for, I need something that's able to run maintenance tasks during development and in production using code from the app (ie rake for ruby), and I was hopping a solution already exists